# Why isn't my Storm topology keeping up?

Tags: performance, apache-storm

My hardware configuration:

- 2 x Nimbus: 2 x 1 CPU @ 10 Core/20 Thread (CentOS reports 40 cores)
- 19 x Supervisors: 2 x 1 CPU @ 12 Core/24 Thread (CentOS reports 48 cores)
- All disks are 10K spindles or faster
- All chassis are at 128GB RAM
- 10gbit interconnects
- Kafka has 40 partitions

My topology is doing simple, low-CPU work.  It takes a JSON object of about 25 kilobytes, unpacks it, queries a few webservices (each in a different bolt), transforms it to a new object, and sends this new object to a final webservice.

I'm not timing out any tuples, the CPU usage on my machines is all very low.

[image: Storm topology after some time]

I wrote a small application to ping ZooKeeper and get offsets, and compare these with Kafka queue depths.  The timestamp is from this morning.  The offset is summed across all 40 partitions of Kafka, the ZooKeeper offsets are summed across all 20 consumers.  The "lag" column is the difference, and the values in parenthesis are the differences between each heartbeat (every 15 seconds).  The first line shows that the offsets grew by 7 messages, but the lag increased by 13.  This means 20 messages came in, but only 7 were processed.  When the topology starts initially, it will keep up, and then slowly fall behind.

```
[7/26/2017 10:34:50 AM] Offset 35535228, lag 53983 (7, 13)
[7/26/2017 10:35:05 AM] Offset 35535234, lag 53990 (6, 7)
[7/26/2017 10:35:21 AM] Offset 35535237, lag 53992 (3, 2)
[7/26/2017 10:35:36 AM] Offset 35535243, lag 53998 (6, 6)
[7/26/2017 10:35:54 AM] Offset 35535247, lag 54004 (4, 6)
[7/26/2017 10:36:10 AM] Offset 35535251, lag 54013 (4, 9)
[7/26/2017 10:36:27 AM] Offset 35535258, lag 54018 (7, 5)
[7/26/2017 10:36:43 AM] Offset 35535267, lag 54024 (9, 6)
[7/26/2017 10:36:59 AM] Offset 35535276, lag 54028 (9, 4)
[7/26/2017 10:37:15 AM] Offset 35535283, lag 54041 (7, 13)
[7/26/2017 10:37:31 AM] Offset 35535293, lag 54063 (10, 22)
[7/26/2017 10:37:46 AM] Offset 35535310, lag 54078 (17, 15)
[7/26/2017 10:38:02 AM] Offset 35535320, lag 54084 (10, 6)
[7/26/2017 10:38:17 AM] Offset 35535326, lag 54091 (6, 7)
[7/26/2017 10:38:33 AM] Offset 35535330, lag 54100 (4, 9)
[7/26/2017 10:38:48 AM] Offset 35535334, lag 54103 (4, 3)
[7/26/2017 10:39:04 AM] Offset 35535339, lag 54116 (5, 13)
[7/26/2017 10:39:21 AM] Offset 35535342, lag 54120 (3, 4)
[7/26/2017 10:39:36 AM] Offset 35535349, lag 54124 (7, 4)
[7/26/2017 10:39:52 AM] Offset 35535351, lag 54134 (2, 10)
[7/26/2017 10:40:08 AM] Offset 35535355, lag 54142 (4, 8)
[7/26/2017 10:40:23 AM] Offset 35535357, lag 54146 (2, 4)
[7/26/2017 10:40:39 AM] Offset 35535359, lag 54149 (2, 3)
[7/26/2017 10:40:54 AM] Offset 35535365, lag 54160 (6, 11)
```

Where do I look next?

Comment: I would look at storm back pressure. Main reasons are normally that bolt buffers are over the water mark or max spout pending is set too low.

Comment: @jamborta: backpressure is disabled and max spout pending is 5000.

Comment: It is hard one to answer directly, since you have Couple of bolts, I recommend to just run Storm with Spout (No bolts) and then it might help in making an informed decision.

Answer (score 0):

Bryan, try to set number ackers also for your topology, I can see only 2 ackers executers are running for your topology, you can set number of ackers with this conf.setNumAckers(10).

This should solve your problem.

If I'm not wrong, topology starts failing tuples after some time right?

Comment: The topology does not fail tuples over time, and changing the ackers to 10 (why that number?) does not help.

Comment: 10 is just a random number, you can choose any number, best is choose same number as many workers are created.